# c++: Generate random numbers with seed

Tags: c++

I am new to c++. I am trying to generate 4 random unique numbers from 0 to 9. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>  
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



int main()

{ 

vector<int> vect;
int randNums = 4;
int countSameNums = 0;
int randNumber; 

srand(time(0));  // Initialize random number generator by setting the seed
// generate 4 random unique integers and insert them all into a vector
while (true){
    randNumber = rand()%10;
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++){
        if (randNumber == vect[i]){
            countSameNums += 1;
        }
    }
    if (countSameNums == 0){
        vect.push_back(randNumber);
        countSameNums = 0;
    }
    if (vect.size() == randNums)
        break;
}

for (int el : vect){ // print out the content of the vector
    cout << el <<endl;
}

}
```

I can compile the code without problems. However when I run it, sometimes it prints out the correct result, i.e. the 4 unique integers, but other times the program just hangs. I also notice that If I comment the line `srand(time(0))` (my random seed) it prints 4 unique numbers every time, i.e. the program never hangs. The problem of course is that by commenting `srand(time(0))` I get always the same sequence of unique numbers and I want a different sequence every run. Any idea on why this isn't working? thanks

Comment: Once `countSameNums` is not 0 you no longer add random numbers to the vector.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That seems a much better way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: An easy way to do this is add 0 to 9 to a vector and shuffle: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: Using % will stop each number being equally likely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator

Comment: The [random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) also has an example which shows how to use C++ newer and improved random number generators, rather than the older and less randomy `rand` and its seed setter `srand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take long before you get 4 different numbers. There is a simpler and more efficient way to get 4 unique numbers. Take a vector containung number from 0 till 9, shuffle it, take the first 4.

Anyhow the issue in your code is that once `countSameNum` is not `0` you will never reset it to `0`. You only reset it when it is `0` already. Change it like this:

```
while (true){
    randNumber = rand()%10;
    countSameNums = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++){
        if (randNumber == vect[i]){
            countSameNums += 1;
        }
    }
    if (countSameNums == 0){
        vect.push_back(randNumber);
    }
    if (vect.size() == randNums)
        break;
}
```

As this is rather error-prone you should rather use `std::find` to see if the number is already in the vector:

```
if (std::find(vect.begin(),vect.end(),randNumber) == vect.end()) vect.push_back(randNumber);
```

And as mentioned before, there are better ways to get unique random numbers.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks for the alternative suggestions!